# Bash - Rename ".tmp" files recursively

Tags: bash

A bunch of Word & Excel documents were being moved on the server when the process terminated before it was complete. As a result, we're left with several perfectly fine files that have a .tmp extension, and we need to rename these files back to the appropriate .xlsx or .docx extension.

Here's my current code to do this in Bash:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "$(find . -type f -name *.tmp)"; do
    ft="$(file "$i")"
    case "$(file "$i")" in
        "$i: Microsoft Word 2007+")
            mv "$i" "${i%.tmp}.docx"
            ;;
        "$i: Microsoft Excel 2007+")
            mv "$i" "${i%.tmp}.xlsx"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

It seems that while this does search recursively, it only does 1 file. If it finds an initial match, it doesn't go on to rename the rest of the files. How can I get this to loop correctly through the directories recursively without it doing just 1 file at a time?

Comment: Don't use `find` this way.  See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a detailed explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too would recommend using `find`.  I would do this in two passes of `find`:

```
find . -type f -name \*.tmp \
 -exec sh -c 'file "{}" | grep -q "Microsoft Word 2007"' \; \
 -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; echo mv "$f" "${f%.tmp}.docx"' \;

find . -type f -name \*.tmp \
 -exec sh -c 'file "{}" | grep -q "Microsoft Excel 2007"' \; \
 -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; echo mv "$f" "${f%.tmp}.xlsx"' \;
```

Lines are split for readability.

Each instance of `find` will search for tmp files, then use `-exec` to test the output of `find`.  This is similar to how you're doing it within the while loop in your shell script, only it's launched from within `find` itself.  We're using the pipe to `grep` instead of your case statement.

The second `-exec` only gets run if the first one returned "true" (i.e. `grep -q ...` found something), and executes the rename in a tiny shell instance.

I haven't profiled this to see whether it would be faster or slower than a loop in a shell script.  Just another way to handle things.

Comment: `{}` is not supposed to be used that way. It allows for arbitrary code injection. Instead, use it as: `-exec sh -c '... do stuff with "$0"...' {} \;`. Like so it'll be completely protected (understand: like so, you're not mixing code and data).

Answer (score 2):

Try `find` command like this:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
    ft="$(file "$i")"
    case "$ft" in
        "$i: Microsoft Word 2007+")
            mv "$i" "${i%.tmp}.docx"
            ;;
        "$i: Microsoft Excel 2007+")
            mv "$i" "${i%.tmp}.xlsx"
            ;;
    esac
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.tmp' -print0)
```

- Using `<(...)` is called process substitution to run `find` command here
- Quote filename pattern in `find`
- Use `-print0` to get `find` output delimited by a null character to allow space/newline characters in file names
- Use `IFS=` and `-d ''` to read null separated filenames